# Issues in Logo image in navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know how to put the logo image on the left and sign in and signup button on the right. Besides, how to put them inside on the navigation bar?

This is the working example of my code in the snippet below:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/*Menu*/

Logo {
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 2px 6px 0;
  position: fixed;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  justify-content: space-between;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arvo;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #27D05F;
  transition: ease 1s;
  color: #fff;
}


/*Dropdownmenu*/

nav ul li ul li {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 2px 6px 0;
}

nav ul:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Aunty Grocery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="w3-container w3-center w3-animate-left">
    <!--Logo-->
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="Image/Logo.png" alt="" width="50" height="50">
    </div>
    <!--Navigation-->
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="grocery.html">Grocery</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="vegetables.html">Vegetables</a></li>
          <li><a href="meats.html">Meats</a></li>
          <li><a href="fish.html">Fish</a></li>
          <li><a href="fruits.html">Fruits</a></li>
          <li><a href="bakery.html">Bakery</a></li>
          <li><a href="others.html">Others</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="career.html">Career</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!--Account-->
  <a class="Register" href="Register.html"><button>Sign Up</button></a>
  <a class="Login" href="Login.html"><button>Sign In</button></a>
</body>

</html>
```

This is the final output of what I achieved with the codes that I have provided earlier:

[image]

Comment: Use jsfiddle.net to make a live example someone can help you with.

Comment: @TJBlackman ok,thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can just cut the logo and buttons and paste in the `<li>` like so

Apart from this there are some issues which I have pointed and corrected

- `<button>` inside `<a>` is not a good code
- the grocery menu opens even when I hover some other area of the menu, it should open only when you hover over grocery

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}


/*Menu*/

Logo {
  float: left;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 2px 6px 0;
  position: fixed;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  justify-content: space-between;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Arvo;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #27D05F;
  transition: ease 1s;
  color: #fff;
}


/*Dropdownmenu*/

nav ul li ul li {
  display: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 2px 6px 0;
}

nav ul li#food_items:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}

#signup_btn,
#signin_btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Aunty Grocery</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="w3-container w3-center w3-animate-left">
    <!--Logo-->

    <!--Navigation-->
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="logo">
          <img src="Image/Logo.png" alt="" width="50" height="50">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
      <li id="food_items"><a href="grocery.html">Grocery</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="vegetables.html">Vegetables</a></li>
          <li><a href="meats.html">Meats</a></li>
          <li><a href="fish.html">Fish</a></li>
          <li><a href="fruits.html">Fruits</a></li>
          <li><a href="bakery.html">Bakery</a></li>
          <li><a href="others.html">Others</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="career.html">Career</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li>
        <button id="signup_btn" onclick="window.location.href='/Register.html'">Sign Up</button></a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <button id="signin_btn" onclick="window.location.href='/Login.html'">Sign In</button></a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!--Account-->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use flexbox in the nav element to do this layout

```css
nav {
  display: flex; // with this option you set the nav as flex container
  align-items: center; // with this option you center your flex elements (the logo for example) in the y axis
  justify-content: space-between; // with this option you set dynamically the left and right space in the flex items (like the logo)
}
```

here you can see the final implementation https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-cdn-k92lp?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: This answer would be vastly improved if you move enough info from the link you've provided into your answer to have an actual answer here. Posts are evaluated with the assumption that any links don't exist or are dead (i.e. that only the actual content in the post exists). Links off-site for *supplementary* or *supporting* information are good, but there needs to be enough in your answer to actually answer the question. Right now this answer is just "you can use flexbox", which is, at best, a very poor answer. So, please include enough from your link to actually answer.